# Is it mandatory in spring form handling, that the form must have all fields corresponding to the model attribute

Tags: forms, spring-mvc

Controller Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/service/userservice/authenticate.action" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
String authenticate(@ModelAttribute("user") User user ,BindingResult errors){ ..... }
```

User class:

```
Class User{
   String userName;
   String password;
   String email;
   ... default Constructor + getters and setters...
}
```

Spring Form:

```
<form:form action="service/userservice/authenticate.action" commandName="user" method="post"> 
  UserID:<form:input  path="userName"/>
  <form:errors path="userName" cssClass="error" /></br>
  Password<form:password  path="password"/>
  <form:errors path="password" cssClass="error" /></br>
  <input type="submit">
```

Should this work or will it give exception :

java.lang.IllegalStateException:Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work fine provided other attributes like email will not be set in object and hence will not be saved.

2nd Part 
(java.lang.IllegalStateException:Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute.)

you may get this exception when you don't add binding object in model for GET Request for displaying view.